# Best approach when dealing with post request data using C without consuming unnecessary memory

Tags: c, http-post

Im creating a web app and already working on the backend. I need to process a lot of post request data using C and API's provided in appweb.

Here's the code:

```
static void addStudentInformation()
{
    char * average = malloc(30000);
    MprJson * userInput = httpGetParams(getConn());

    char * name;
    strcpy(name,mprLookupJson(userInput, "name"));

    average = computeGrade(mprLookupJson(userInput, "gradeSubject1_1"),   mprLookupJson(userInput, "gradeSubject1_2"), mprLookupJson(userInput, "gradeSubject1_3"));

   //more function calls

}

char * computeGrade(char * grade1, char * grade2, char * grade3)
{
    /*process grade*/
    return average;
}

//more function
```

As you can see, the value returned by mprLookupJson was directly used a a parameter in function computeGrade. I thought of not storing those values in a variable since it wont needed/ used in addStudentInformation. I thought that there's no point of alloting/using a memory. Now, my question **is it safe/good practice to do that? is there any possibility that a security issue may arise because of that**? What would be the best approach for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Several "good practices" would include **1)** Checking the return value of `malloc`, **2)** Not passing an uninitialized `char*` to `strcpy`... And by "good practices" I mean "common-sense things that every C programmer should know".

Comment: If you're looking for a security audit, you'll need to supply more code (e.g. the `mprLookupJson` function), and you should post the question on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @user3386109 - yey thanks for pointing out. I didnt know about Code Review before. :)

Comment: "*What would be the best approach for this?*" For what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if `mpfLookupJson(userInput, "name")` does not find a valid entry? Say, it delivers -1 as it has not found an entry. In that case, your `strcpy()` could crash.

If `mpfLookupJson` finds something valid, it will allocate some memory on the heap and give you the pointer to it. In that case, the memory has already been allocated. If you create a further pointer variable to it, in my opinion it won't matter. If you program some special micro controller, maybe you have to care about some bytes more or less, but probably not here.

Now you create a pointer variable `name` and try to *copy* the value found to where `name` points to. As long as you don't allocate memory for `name` to point to, this will crash. Further: do you really need a copy of the value found by `mpfLookupJson`? Can't you use it as it has been returned?

To my eyes, this would be enough, more reliable and more readable:

```
static void addStudentInformation()
{
    char * average = malloc(30000);
    MprJson * userInput = httpGetParams(getConn());

    char * name;
    char * grade1;
    char * grade2;
    char * grade3;

    name = mprLookupJson(userInput, "name");
    grade1 = mprLookupJson(userInput, "gradeSubject1_1");
    grade2 = mprLookupJson(userInput, "gradeSubject1_2");
    grade3 = mprLookupJson(userInput, "gradeSubject1_3");

    if (name <= 0 || grade1 <= 0 || grade2 <= 0 || grade3 <= 0 ) {
        // handle error and / or abort 
    } 

    average = computeGrade(grade1, grade2, grade3);

    //more function calls

    ...
 }
```

Then, what happens after the end of the function? If memory is important to you, make sure you deallocate everything the right way.

These are rather safety concerns than security concerns. Security starts where somebody can misuse your code to get admin privileges or make the process crash or the memory being flooded. The first points to examine would be what `mprLookupJson` precisely does, how good `userInput` has been filtered against tampering and how strict you react if `name`, `grade1`, `grade2` etc. are invalid the slightest way. Alone for this reasons, you need well readable code.

Hope these suggestions are a good start :-)